# How to maintain history when TFS branch is created

Tags: tfs

I am creating an new branch from existing branch using Source Control Explorer (TFS) in Visual Studio 2012.
I can't see any history from the original branch in the new branch.
Is there any way to force copy of original branch history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new branch contains the history of original branch. You need to check history for a single file (not a folder), then you should see the history:

[image]